# Rails stop processing controller after time out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application that takes some user input, does hours of processing on it and returns the file to the user. Because this takes so long to process, the client can sometimes time out receiving a "connection reset by peer" error.

To alleviate that issue I want to just upload the file to AWS instead of returning it to the user. My question is, if the connection times out before all of the processing and uploading is done, does rails immediately stop processing the controller action?

Comment: if the process is so complex that rails times out, you should use a background job to perform it.

Comment: haha I have no idea why I didn't just think of that first. So frustrating lol.